# I want to install a combo switch/outlet to my existing bathroom light switch

Tags: electrical

I currently only have a single hot & neutral wire to the switch for my light. Can I install a combo switch/outlet?

Comment: Are you sure they're hot and neutral? If you have two wires, it's far more likely its a hot and a switched hot. Can you post some pictures or a diagram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No not if there's only 1 cable in the box. That's not Hot and Neutral, but Hot and switch leg.